# Is action bar present by default in android version 3.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am developing app, but i want interface which look similar to action bar, i was trying to implement manually for my android 2.2 SDK.

But after going through a article here http://android.ankara-gtug.org/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html.

it says, Action bar is present by default on 3.0 Android onwards, can we get direct drag and drop access?

what about the devices 1.6 android? does they support this APK. kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is a great resource that allows the use of the `ActionBar` on pre-HoneyComb devices. You can find real world applications of the library on the [implementations page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/wiki/Implementations) and sample code and documentation at the [samples page](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an Action Bar that can be used down to 1.6 then try [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

EDIT:

To use them visit the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) usage page and the [Android Action Bar page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

> When creating an activity to use the action bar on all versions of Android, you must declare your activity to extend any of the activity classes that start with 'Sherlock' (e.g., SherlockActivity, SherlockFragmentActivity). Interaction with the action bar is handled by calling getSupportActionBar() (instead of getActionBar()).

Comment: Any example on how to use them, please provide some link